# Reverse Map.key, map.value output

Tags: java, output, reverse

I have this output and it comes out in the opposite order. The last printout is what i want to be the first print out. How can I reverse it? It is a HashMap.

```
System.out.println();
            int c = 0;
            System.out.print(newName + "= ");
            for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : result.entrySet()) {

                System.out.print(entry.getValue() + "X^" + entry.getKey());
                c++;
                if (c != result.size()) {
                    System.out.print("+");
                }
```

Comment: Which type of map have you used? HashMap?

Comment: Maps don't have any guaranteed order, in general. If you want a particular order, you should sort the output yourself. On the other hand, if this is a sorted map, you should just sort with the reverse order. We can't tell based on just what you've specified here.

Comment: Consider using `TreeMap` to sort.

Comment: Reverse it by using `TreeMap` and providing a `Comparator` that does what you want

Answer (score 3):

To preserve insertion order when iterating use a [`LinkedHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) instead of a `HashMap`, and to go in reverse do this:

```
List<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> entries = new ArrayList<>(result.entrySet());
Collections.reverse(entries);

for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : entries) {
    // same body as before
}
```

Alternatively, we can use a reverse iterator:

```
List<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> entries = new ArrayList<>(result.entrySet());
ListIterator<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> iter = entries.listIterator();

while (iter.hasPrevious()) {
    Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry = iter.previous();
    // same body as before
}
```

Comment: How is this the same as before?

Comment: @Dave I meant: copy the same loop body inside my new loops

Comment: OK the first one kinda worked but one of the values was still misplaced. The second one didn't seem to work at all. didn't print the output.

Comment: @Dave did you use a `LinkedHashMap`? if not, it won't work. And for the second loop notice that you _must_ use the `entry` local variable. It's impossible to help you if you don't post the whole code that's relevant to what you're trying to do